# Difference between calling prototype method directly vs instance method?

Tags: javascript

What would be the difference between the two types of calling `bar` below?

```
function Foo(){

}

Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log('bar called');
};

Foo.prototype.bar();
new Foo().bar();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abn6gfm0/

Comment: Try `console.log('bar called in', this);`

Comment: `myObject.myMethod()` invokes `myMethod()` with `myObject` set as the value of `this` in the method. So look at your two calls. They will have different `this` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Denys points out in the comments, the `this` context will be different. The first call will set `this` to reference Foo.prototype, while the second sets `this` to Foo.

Another difference is if you override the bar() function in Foo. This will effectively mask the prototype and the second call will be to the function override.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.prototype.bar()` calls the method present in class's Foo prototype.

With the prototype declartion you are saying: all Foo objects will have a method bar(). And with the above command you call the method bar() that will be copied to every instance (use of `new` keyword).

`new Foo().bar()` calls the method attached to a instance of bar

You're creating a new object of type Foo (which contains a method bar()) and then calling the bar() method in it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Foo() {
    this.some = 'Instance';
}

Foo.prototype.some = 'Permanent';
Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log( this.some );
};

Foo.prototype.bar();
new Foo().bar();

var a = { some: 'MyText' }
Foo.prototype.bar.call(a)
```